# como fazer o refresh automático no zabbix web

Tags: zabbix

estou com um problema no zabbix, instalei o configurei as templates no host criado e monitora porém não está atualizando automático ou seja estou tendo que dá um refresh na pagina do zabbix web para poder ver as informações atualizadas alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema estou usando uma maquina virtual com sistema ubuntu 14.04 e o zabbix 3.0